# Are these two distinct series representations for $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$.

With a $u=x^2$ substitution, $f(x)$ becomes $g(u)=\frac{1}{1-u}$, which being the limit of a geometric series has the form $$g(u)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty u^k$$

Plugging the substitution back in yields a power series representation for $f(x)$

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (x^2)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}$$

A different approach would be to factor the denominator of $f(x)$

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}=\frac{1}{1+x}\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1+x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{1+x}$$

Here we have two different series representations for the same function but the second one is not a power series representation, so I'm guessing there's no issues here (unless I've made some mistake in either of my derivations).

Comment: Doesn't $g=(1\color{red}{+} u)^{-1}$?

Comment: $i<x$: you're kidding? Which order on $\mathbf C$ do you have?

Comment: @Bacon I made the correction, had the wrong u substitution I was thinking of the + problem earlier.

Comment: @Bernard Did you read my question carefully? There was a part following this saying "which doesn't make sense."

Also, in all likelihood a 2nd year calculus student asking this question would not have the mathematical maturity to discuss orderings of the complex numbers, better not open this can of worms and focus on remedying more basic and immediate misunderstandings.

Comment: I think you should have ended your display equation with $\implies0\le x^2<1$, whence $-1<x<1$ in this case too. And  as far as I know, non-ordering of complex numbers is known in high school.

Comment: @Bernard That's true, I got rid of that part to keep the two derivations, the second answer made a very nice connection between the two.


Off topic, but I would be very impressed with the educational system that manages to make 17 year olds comprehend the words "The set of complex numbers cannot be totally ordered." I'd say it takes 4 years of undergraduate mathematics to begin understanding anything about the set of complex numbers at a fundamental level.

Comment: In high school they don't know it formally, but the teacher can make the observation that a square has to be positive by the rule of signs, and $i^2=-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{x^k}{1 + x} &= \sum_{k \ge 0} \sum_{\ell \ge k} (-1)^{\ell-k}x^\ell \\
&= \sum_{\ell \ge 0} \sum_{k \le \ell} (-1)^{\ell-k}x^\ell \\
&= \sum_{\ell \ge 0} x^\ell \sum_{k \le \ell} (-1)^{\ell-k}
\end{align}

where

$$ \sum_{k \le \ell} (-1)^{\ell-k} = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $\ell$ is odd} \\ 1 & \text{if $\ell$ is even} \end{cases}. \tag{1} $$

In fact, the formal identity
$$ \sum_{\ell \ge 0} x^\ell \sum_{k \le \ell} (-1)^{\ell-k} = \frac{1}{1 - x^2} $$
is a great way to prove $(1)$.

Answer (score 3):

$|x^2|<1\iff-1<x^2<1\iff 0\leqslant x^2<1\text{ (because $x^2\geqslant0$)}\iff x\in(-1,1)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, obvious mistake I made there. I've edited the question to get rid of this side part, my main question regarded the relation between the two series representations and whether there's any mistakes in either derivation.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with

$$f (x)=\frac {1}{1-x^2}=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}a_{2i}x^{2i} $$

we have

$$1=(1-x^2)f (x)=$$
$$a_0+\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}(a_{2i}-a_{2i-2})x^{2i}$$

thus
$$a_{2i}=a_{2i-2}=...=a_0=f (0)=1$$